# Will the Kernel module load when there is no initialization function?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I am writing a driver code for first time. I have checked many resources which state that the initialization function for a kernel module is either init_module() or any another function that is specified using MODULE_INIT() macro. And this initialization function is called when a kernel module is loaded.

But I could not find any information about what happens when initialization function doesn't exist in a Loadable kernel module and is tried to load.

What would be the scenario if the kernel module is in-tree and doesn't have initialization function??

---Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the routine `do_init_module`, it tests whether an init routine is provided.  If not, it just skips the call.  See https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.10.108/source/kernel/module.c#L3092

```
if (mod->init != NULL)
    ret = do_one_initcall(mod->init);
```

Comment: Does it mean the module is not loaded or can't be loaded??

Comment: No.  It loads the module and it is as though `init` succeeded.

Comment: There's no reason not to have an init call, though.  Typically, you would want to log that your module has been loaded, and then just return success.

Comment: @stark: "Typically, you would want to log that your module has been loaded, and then just return success." - Typically in the `init` function you would want to **register** all real devices and/or pseudo devices (like a filesystem) for which your module provides a driver. Logging that your module is loaded is the last thing one is bother. Without `init` function a module could only provide some functions for other modules, which could be loaded later.

Comment: @stark, there are plenty of modules that are *libraries*, they do not have `->init()` defined.